# Persist url query data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using react and in some pages i am transferring data from url but the problem is when I want that data to persist if url changes until there is any other query or parameter in url.
How can i achieve that?

This is my url  snapshot
[image]

I want the query data i.e idx=1 to persist if there is any change in url like this
[image]

Currently when I link to salesfunnel page I am doing this

`

```
componentDidMount() {
    var url = this.props.location.query;
    this.setState({
      selid : parseInt(url.idx, 10)
    })
  }
```

`

and in that case i lost query.I want that the query should remain somewhere with me if i get it once and the data should only change when there is certain change in query of url for eg: if idx=2 from idx=1.

How can i achieve that in react?

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: So you're parsing the parameter and storing it in state .. what is the problem?

Comment: Are you using react router? When the url changes does this use the default browser change or is it handled using javascript somehow?

Comment: problem is that i want that data with me till any other query for eg. (idx=2) or something like this changes. If i link to some other page then the url will change but i want that data with me if url changes.

Comment: @spirift Yes i am using react router. And no, the default browser change.. I am not handing anything..

Answer (score 0):

Can you not conditionally set the `selid` e.g.:

```
componentDidMount() {
  var url = this.props.location.query;
  if (url.idx) {
    // Only update `selid` when `idx` is a query param
    this.setState({
      selid : parseInt(url.idx, 10)
    });
  }
}
```

This way you'll persist the value across page changes until the user lands on a new page that sets a new `idx`.

Comment: No,I cant because if I switch to another page and when I switch to this page I will lost the previous selid and I can't persist the existing selid